# ¿Cómo hago un chat con postMessage?

Tags: javascript

postMessage es una "función"... que sirve para "mandar mensajes" y bueno, eso que la estuve probando, y me dí cuenta de que no se posteaba ningún mensaje, si es para eso para lo que servía la función esta. Así que pasado un rato hice una pregunta en stackOverflow, y alguien me escribió, no me acuerdo donde, que para que un postMessage funcionara, tenía que usar un Worker. Con un worker, no se enviaba información, así que decidí sustituirlo por un SharedWorker, que es como un Worker que es como más en plan público, se supone, así que me puse a enrrear y llegué a crear estos dos archivos:

chat7.js

```
uq=0
ports=[]
self.addEventListener("connect",function(event1){
uq++
port=event1.ports[0]
ports.push(port)
port.start()
port.addEventListener("message",function(event2){for(i in ports){ports[i].postMessage(event2.data)}},false)
for(i in ports){ports[i].postMessage("Chat users are now: "+uq)}
},false)
```

Chat7.html

```
<body>
<script>
document.body.style.backgroundColor="black"
worker=new SharedWorker("chat v7.js","net")
worker.port.start()
worker.port.addEventListener("message",function(event){console.log(event.data)},false)
worker.port.addEventListener("error",function(event){console.log("Error "+event.data)},false)
onkeydown=function(e){if(e.keyCode==13){
worker.port.postMessage(prompt("Enter your message."))
}}
</script>
</body>
```

Entonces, intenté probar esto en mi ordenador, y no me dejaba crear un SharedWorker. Lo subí a hostinger, y se me comunica entre ventana y ventana en una misma computadora, pero no en computadoras distintas. ¿Ustedes saben cómo arreglar esto, de manera que este chat se pueda abrir para que los mensajes se detecten desde cualquier proceso que contacte con la página y el "SharedWorker" envíe la información a todos los procesos? Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Para comenzar, deberías formatear mejor tu código. Está muy difícil de leerlo. Sobre tu pregunta, si quieres hacer un aplicativo de ese tipo, el camino a seguir es usando **`websockets`**. Si, no tienes experiencia con ello, utiliza una librería como [**`Socket.io`**](http://socket.io/) para abstraerte de las partes complejas.

Comment: Tengo otra pregunta que se relacciona con tu mención:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27846/como-se-usan-los-websocket-en-un-archivo-de-html

Answer (score 2):

Es que **`postMessage` no es para eso.** Ese método, sirve para **comunicar en el mismo navegador** distintas partes (por lo tanto, en la misma PC):

- Comunicar scripts de **distintos orígenes** ([`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)). Por ejemplo, supongamos que en tu página tudominio.com tenés incrustado un reproductor de video de otrodominio.com, con el cual querés comunicarte.
- Comunicar scripts de **distintos hilos** ([`Worker.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage), etc.). Por ejemplo, en una página web elegís qué archivo abrir, ves cuánto está tardando, podés cancelarlo, etc. Y a la vez, en otro hilo pero de la misma página (para eso son los Workers) tenés otro script haciendo las tareas pesadas (descomprimir el archivo, convertirlo a HTML, etc.).

Si querés hacer una **aplicación web de mensajería instantánea**, tenés distintas opciones (casi todas requieren de cierta programación del servidor). Por ejemplo:

- Usar un **servidor con WebSocket** (como [socket.io](http://socket.io/)) u otra tecnología similar para que la web establezca una comunicación permanente. Algunos son gratis si el uso es limitado.
- Usar un **servidor más común** ([PHP](http://php.net), por ejemplo), y **recargar** cada tanto los mensajes nuevos. Para esto podés hacerlo vía AJAX (lo más liviano), o simplemente recargar la página (más pesado, pero útil cuando el navegador del usuario no tiene la tecnología suficiente).
- Usar [WebRTC](http://webrtc.org), que es un **protocolo de conexión punto a punto**. Es decir, para conectar dos usuarios (con distintas computadoras), **evitando el uso de un servidor intermediario** para las comunicaciones.

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda, ¡saludos!

PD: Algunos recursos adicionales al respecto, que pueden serte útiles:

- **[Usando WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Usando_web_workers)**: Es una guía **en español** sobre el uso de esta herramienta, que sirve para realizar varias tareas a la vez.
- **[API de WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API)**: Es una guía **en español** sobre el uso de la API de WebRTC, con ejemplos y todo.
- **[PeerJS Demo Chat](http://cdn.peerjs.com/demo/chat.html)** Es un ejemplo del uso de PeerJS, una biblioteca (dejemos de traducir *library* como *libería*, por favor) que parece facilitar el uso de WebRTC.
- **[WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets-840092-dup)**: Es una guía **en español** sobre la API del navegador de este protocolo, que permite una comunicación en tiempo real con un servidor.
- **[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/AJAX)**: Es una guía **en español** sobre esta combinación de tecnologías.

Comment: ¿Y no se podría usar una base de datos mejor?

Comment: **NO**, son problemas distintos, @TatoBroh. La base de datos es para *almacenar* información. Lo que vos querés es *comunicar* información.

Comment: Si usás un servidor como intermediario de la comunicación, podés o no usar base de datos; si usás una comunicación directa, podés o no usar base de datos. Pero **seguirías sin resolver el problema de la comunicación**.

Comment: Por el tipo de confusión que demuestran tus preguntas, parece que te estás adelantando en querer hacer algo sin los conocimientos previos. Primero, tenés que entender el funcionamiento básico de una computadora, del modelo cliente-servidor, de las comunicaciones web, etc.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción es que utilices librerias o plataformas que te pueden ayudar en lo que necesitas, como socket.io o firebase:

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/demos/chat/)

Comment: Tu respuesta se enfoca hacia la utilización de un script externo "node.js", sin embargo, esos scripts están alojados en una plataforma y están ya programados lo cual hace que esos scripts se ejecuten con desconocimiento y el programador no pueda usar con exactitud la función "postMessage", así que se recomienda editar la respuesta añadiendo una información que aclare aspectos o funciones base en el uso de la función que se menciona en la pregunta.

Comment: @TatoBroh Algunas aclaraciones: 1) El servidor no tiene por qué ser remoto, podés instalarlo en alguna PC tuya.

Comment: 2) Si bien el script corre en el servidor, en la práctica eso no significa usualmente a) que tengas menos control, b) ni tampoco que tengas real control si la página estática de todas formas se hospeda en un servidor remoto.

Comment: 3) Como explico en mi respuesta, `postMessage` no es para comunicarse con el servidor.

Comment: Te recomendaría aclarar si la función postMessage requiere de un código que se pueda ejecutar en el navegador o bien requiere de un código que se deba ejecutar fuera del navegador y qué código debería ser.

Comment: Como dije en mi respuesta, `postMessage` no sirve para lo que querés, se ejecuta en el navegador *pero no tiene comunicación por sí mismo con otros navegadores*.

Comment: Si quisiera usar socket.io, tendría que abrir los puertos de mi router, para así poder usar nodejs desde mi compu de manera gratis. Respondeme a esta cuestión si puedes:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51783/por-qu%C3%A9-cuando-cargo-el-dominio-ddns-asociado-a-la-ip-p%C3%BAblica-de-mi-router-huaw

Comment: Hola, no. No hace falta que abras el puerto en el router. Lo que sí hace falta es que lo abras en tu computadora (lo que no implica que esté abierto hacia afuera).

Comment: Entonces solo funcionará en la red local.