# ¿Como se usan los WebSocket en un archivo de html?

Tags: javascript, html5

Hice esta función en un server esy.es:

```
<script>
net=new WebSocket("ws://tatopatato.esy.es/chat12.htm")
</script>
```

Y me da un error:

> Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en ws://tatopatato.esy.es/chat12.htm.

En chrome ocurre algo parecido, además si pongo esto:

```
<body bgcolor="black">
<script>
name=prompt("Enter your name, please.")
net=new WebSocket('ws://html5rocks.websocket.org/echo')
net.onmessage=function(){e.data}
net.onconnect=function(){net.send(console.log("User: "+name+" has connected"))}
onkeydown=function(){net.send(console.log(prompt("Enter your message.")))}
</script>
</body>
```

Es curioso, porque cuando envío un mensaje no responde. ¿Qué hago para que funcione?

Answer (score 2):

Tenès que conectarte a un servidor WS. No a un archivo HTML.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets-840092-dup/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: ¿Y cómo se hace un servidor ws?

Comment: ¿en què lenguaje? Es un servidor, como un servidor HTTP... pero cuyo protocolo es el protoclo WS. NodeJS podrìa ser una opciòn, si te interesa edito la respuesta con un poco mas de informaciòn.

Comment: Un momento, WebSocket depende de node.js de manera que tiene que redirigir a esa página para funcionar?

Comment: No... WS es un protocolo. Como HTTP. Por lo tanto, con cualquier lenguaje podés hacer un cliente/servidor que implemente ese protocolo. de la misma manera que podés escribir un servidor HTTP en C++, lo podés escribir en JavaScript con NodeJS. "WebSocket" no depende Node. 
Lo que vos podrías hacer en Node es escribir el servidor, y decir "bueno, si me llega este mensaje, hago tal cosa, si me llega este otro mensaje, hago tal otra". La página sería la interfaz del cliente, y el servidor lo escribirías en Node.

Comment: Nunca he visto una página web que sea ws://(Nombre), me imagino que es imposible usar WebSocket, por lo que veo...

Comment: No, no... no es imposible. De hecho es muy usado. El tema es el siguiente: vos entràs a una pàgina comùn y corriente, y desde JavaScript, esta establece una conexiòn a un servidor WS.

Ahora en breve edito mi respuesta con un ejemplo funcional, porque veo que te vengo confundiendo mucho. Mis disculpas.

Comment: Te hago una pregunta, ¿sabès manejar NodeJS? Porque estaba por escribir algo, pero me di cuenta que no sabìa eso. ¿Manejàs Node? El servidor lo tenès que desarrollar en algùn lenguaje que soporte sockets berkeley.

Comment: Es que una cosa es el script de socket.io (Que no viene definido en los navegadores) y otra cosa es la función WebSocket, yo hablo de un server que se pueda iniciar gratis usando WebSocket, sin tener que modificar el servidor, o de manera fácil.

Comment: No entiendo lo que decìs. En los navegadores no necesitàs Socket.IO... tenès el objeto WebSocket.

En el servidor si necesitàs una librerìa que los implemente. Tanto Node como las librerìas que hay a disposiciòn son gratuitas.

Comment: Aparte no te nombre Socket.IO en ningùn momento. ¿O estàs buscando algùn servicio online con un servidor WS ya listo para que vos puedas interactuar? No comprendo.

Comment: Pero nombrastes node.js, y eso es un script que tiene que ver con socket.io. Te estoy hablando de las funciones del navegador, no de las funciones de scripts externos como node.js

Comment: NodeJS no es un script, ni tiene nada que ver con Socket IO per sè. NodeJS es un entorno de JavaScript, orientado a la creaciòn de servidores. 

Cuando vos querès usar sockets, necesitàs un cliente y un servidor. En el caso del uso de WebSockets, el cliente es el navegador, y el servidor, es una aplicaciòn remota.

Socket.IO es una librerìa, opcional, que funciona tanto en el navegador, como en el servidor. Si vos no escribìs el servidor websocket, entonces tenès que consumir uno existente; que ya estè online.

Comment: Vos en el cliente (navegador) podès NO usar ninguna librerìa, y usar la API WebSockets. Pero una aplicaciòn que usa sockets es una aplicaciòn TCP comùn y corriente, NECESITA un servidor. Los servidores NO son otro navegadores, si no que son aplicaciones externas, tal como cualquier servidor HTTP, o FTP, o lo que sea.
La API de WebSockets es una API que viene en navegadores modernos, pero no forma parte de ningùn lenguaje, por ende, cuando quieras escribir un servidor WS, vas a tener que recurrir a una librerìa, o escribir tu propia implementaciòn del protocolo (poco probable).

Comment: ¿Y cómo se escribe una implementación del protocolo? ...

Comment: O sea, ya directamente me estás diciendo que tendría que instalar Ubuntu Server para que pudiese crear un chat...

Comment: Un servidor es un programa común y corriente, que atiende peticiones de clientes. Cualquier sistema operativo, y con cualquier lenguaje.

La gente normalmente usa lo que da el lenguaje, o alguna libreria de terceros para laburar en HTTP, generalmente eso ya viene nativo en el lenguaje.

Estás muuuy perdido, es como que no te puedo explicar todo en un comentario.

Comment: Algo hay mal, porque el servidor que puse abajo no funciona trabándose en ocasiones, es muy raro...

Comment: No hiciste ningún servidor ahí... sólo hay dos archivos html...

Comment: No lo hice, pero lo cogí de html5 webrocks...

Comment: El servidor es un programa que escucha en un puerto determinado, bajo una determinada dirección, normalmente en un lugar externo, no un archivo HTML.

Comment: Creo que tuve una idea sobre esto, pronto te informo.