# ¿Por qué cuando cargo el dominio ddns asociado a la IP pública de mi router huawey b310 este rechaza la conexión?

Tags: dns, router

Tengo el siguiente dominio contratado en http://www.dynu.com :
http://medaeditorbyuknown1.dynu.net/

El dominio está asociado a la IP del router gracias a Dynu IP Update Client v4.43 . Cada vez que pasa cierto tiempo Dynu IP Update Client v4.43 va actualizando la IP de mi router, para así evitar fallos.

El problema reside cuando mi computadora está conectada al router de mis padres, Huawey b310 conectado a la red telefónica administrada por Vodafone. Mientras mi computadora está conectada a ese router mi navegador es capaz de cargar la página http://192.168.1.1, pero cuando intenta cargar "http://medaeditorbyuknown1.dynu.net:8000/", da el siguiente error:

> No se puede acceder a este sitio 
>   medaeditorbyuknown1.dynu.net rechazó la conexión.
>   Buscar dynu net 8000 en Google
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

A pesar de que el puerto 8000 redirija a 192.168.1.101:8000 , no se muestra nada, y debería mostrarse el servicio "nodejs" que mi computadora está ejecutando con la cmd.

Y cuando cargo el dominio "http://medaeditorbyuknown1.dynu.net/" mientras mi computadora está conectada al router de mis padres me aparece el siguiente error:

> No se puede acceder a este sitio
>   medaeditorbyuknown1.dynu.net tardó demasiado en responder.
>   Intenta:
>   Comprobar la conexión.
>   Comprobar el proxy y el firewall.
>   Ejecución del Diagnóstico de red de Windows
>   ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Una cosa a destacar es que cuando pruebo a cargar el dominio "http://medaeditorbyuknown1.dynu.net:80/" en el navegador mientras mi computadora está conectada a otro router, muestra la misma página que cuando tecleo http://192.168.1.1 . Esto me pasa en clase de informática y en casa de mis tíos.

El objetivo que pretendo conseguir, es que cuando cargue "http://medaeditorbyuknown1.dynu.net:80/" en el router de mis padres "Huawey b310 conectado a la red telefónica administrada por Vodafone", me aparezca la misma página que cuando teclee "http://192.168.1.1".

Comment: Si hay algún problema de entendimiento les muestro algún esquema aclarando mi problema.

Comment: probablemente el router de tus padres no tiene port forwarding configurado. Tendrías que meterte a su configuración y comprobar si el puerto 8000 está redirigiendo a 192.168.1.1

Comment: Asegúrate de mapear los puertos del modem (exterior) a tu pc (interior). Del mismo modo, tienes que asegurarte que el firewall permite la entrada por el puerto indicado. O agrega tu computadora a la zona desmilitarizada. Revisa la documentación de tu modem para hacerlo.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no parece ser un problema relacionado con la programación.

Comment: Las [Preguntas sobre gestión de servidores y redes de ordenadores que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio Server Fault.](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/166/301) son aceptadas por la comunidad de esSO como parte de la temática del sitio. Voto para mantener abierta.

Comment: Disculpen la mala edicción de la pregunta.

Comment: @toledano
Ya publiqué la página en Server Fault si es lo que querías...

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un pequeño esquema de conexión? Es decir, dónde estás tú cuando haces la conexión, dónde está el servidor que corre la aplicación node.js y dónde está el router y cómo está configurado (la redirección de puertos). También vendría bien saber si tienes redirigidos los puertos en el router o no y si tienes posibilidad de hacerlo (hay routers en los que no puedes hacerlo o no se tienen las credenciales o permisos necesarios para ello).

Comment: No es necesario un esquema, al menos desde mi experiencia personal, sé una alternativa para este problema. Ya os contaré en mi respuesta. De todas formas, sí, puedes quejarte a tu compañía, pero al fin y al cabo si usas el método que pondré en mi respuesta valdrá para TODAS las conexiones a internet establecidas por el usuario. Espero que ayude mi respuesta, y si podéis, ayudéis a mejorar. Lo digo porque abrir el router puede dejar entrar programas destructivos, y habría que proteger bien la IP pública. De todas formas dudo que esta pregunta no sea de programación, ya que...

Comment: ... trata de servicio DHCP y DNS de forma pública y eso.

Vale... mi situación, es. Nadie puede leer los programas que abra por IP local, como UbuntuApache, xampp, nodejs, npm... por mucho que configure mi router, de forma que no funcionan los puertos que se muestran en la tabla así como tampoco funciona el servidor DMZ. Existe una alternativa. Atended a la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Esta es la explicación: http://www.securamente.com/que-es-nat-loopback/ Se llama __NAT llopback__ y es una característica que muchos modems/routers no tienen.

Comment: La alternativa es usar en los equipos locales una VPN. Con eso, la conexión vendrá del exterior y el router la dejará pasar.

Comment: Efectivamente, es un identificador externo para routers que no valen para postear páginas web hacia afuera, con lo cual se intenta hacer una especie de "trampa" para usuarios pobres que no pueden mejorar su contrato debido a que comparten internet con otras personas.

Comment: Es como si yo usara un servicio SSH, solo que esta vez en vez de un servicio SSH estoy publicando los servicios que atienden a los exploradores y terminales desde una IP (Muy similar a lo que hace el router.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy inseguro abrir los puertos de un router, pero si sois tan valientes para hacedlo, se recomiendan los siguientes programas, por si acaso pagáis poco por vuestra wifi como para preocuparos por contratos elevados, podéis montar un servidor desde vuestro hogar, lo cual se recomienda para personas que tengan ordenadores con alta cantidad de GPUs y memoria gráfica, y además que siempre estéis ahí para vigilar el ordenador y que no haya errores con vuestros juegos. Las maneras son la siguientes:
localtunnel:
Se instala con el siguiente comando de terminal (Primero hay que instalar npm):
`>npm install -g localtunnel`
Una vez instalado se inicia con:
`>lt --port 8000`
Ahí se proporcionará un nombre de dominio aleatorio. Y si no os convence podéis probar más alternativas:

`https://ngrok.com/`

`https://pagekite.net/`

`https://forwardhq.com/`

Y el mejor de todos es:

`http://www.ultrahook.com/`

Y con este último tienes subdominio fijo incluido, instalando primero RubyGems:
`https://rubygems.org/pages/download/#formats`
Y uego haciendo los comandos que te pide ultrahook al registrarte.